# Kotlin SAM conversion with private inner Java interface?

Tags: java, kotlin, kotlin-interop

Consider the following Java class:

```
package javapkg;

public class JavaClass {
    private interface JavaInterface {
        void foo();
    }

    public void bar(JavaInterface ji) {
        ji.foo();
    }
}
```

Kotlin code that uses this class's inner interface with a SAM conversion (note that `KotlinClass` is in a different package):

```
package kotlinpkg
import javapkg.JavaClass

class KotlinClass {
    fun f() {
        val jc = JavaClass()
        // Does not compile:
        // "Cannot access 'JavaInterface': it is private in 'JavaClass'"
        jc.bar(object : JavaClass.JavaInterface{
            override fun foo() { }
        })

        // Compiles and runs fine on Android Nougat, but throws
        // a NoClassDefFoundError exception on Kitkat
        jc.bar { }
    }
}
```

Now, if you make the inner `JavaInterface` public, the Kotlin code (both the SAM conversion and the object expression) compiles and runs correctly on all platforms. The object expression fails to compile with the interface being private because `JavaClass` and `KotlinClass` are in separate packages, and I'm guessing the SAM conversion fails with a runtime exception for the same reason.

My question: why does the SAM conversion successfully compile? It seems like it ought not to because the interface is private, and worse it causes a runtime exception in Kitkat. Also, the object expression does NOT compile. Is this a bug in the Kotlin compiler, or is this deliberate?

Comment: I don't why but Java does not have error when exposing private class on public interface. But if the class is written in Kotlin, you cannot compile.

Comment: This sounds like a bug in the kotlin compiler to me... you may want to open an issue at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/KT